# Create a local database in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

After successive failures, I come here to ask for help in desperation.

All I need, is to be able to create and host locally a database, that I can later connect to via SQLDeveloper (preferably, but it can be any other program. That's what my professor recommended us using this year).

I've googled this prior to asking this question, but all I can find is tutorials on how to connect to the database. I first need to create one, in order to connect to it (or at least that's how I understood the concept).

Please give any suggestions, links to tutorials, programs that I need or questions regarding what i actually want all of this for.

Comment: Go to your mysql console and just type: CREATE DATABASE databasename;

Comment: SQLDeveloper? Are you using Oracle?

Comment: SQL Developer is designed for Oracle databases. If it can connect to MySQL, it's possibly just to aid in data migrations to Oracle. Are you positively sure you got all the names right?

Comment: @jarlh yes i'm using oracle, it's for school after all.

Comment: Then you can remove the <mysql> tag and instead add an <oracle> tag.

Comment: Oracle SQL Server is not installed on a OS by default. So depending on your OS you have to install the Oracle SQL Server. You can find documents how to on Oracles website. Nevertheless I find it strange that a teacher is requesting Oracle SQL instead of mySQL which is much easier to handle

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff: I would find it strange if MySQL was recommended and not PostgreSQL ;)

Comment: Just google for "oracle xe" and install the package for your platform.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is the wishful thinking of all PostgreSQL users :-)

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - "Oracle SQL Server" does not even exist.  "Oracle" is the rdbms provided by Oracle Corp.  "SQL Server" is the rdbms provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @EdStevens You are a really bean counter, sorry

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a database you will first need to download and install the software, from [here](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/).

Since this is for school, I'd guess that the 18c Express Edition would be sufficient.  The specific link is on the page for which I provided a link.  When you drill down to the specific database you want (XE, Enterprise Edition, etc) there will also be a link to the installation guide.

Every oracle installation I've seen also offers, as part of the installation dialog, an option to *also* create a database.  But note that creating a database is logically separate from installing the software.  You can also choose to install software only, then later run DBCA (Database Creation Assistant) to create a database.

As you suspect, SQL Dev is just a client.  It is not the database, and doesn't create a database when it is installed.